# python for loop spits out query that is in error

Tags: python, sql, flask

Hi i am reading a  csv file with pandas. i am also creating a new data frame with the fields i want. as i iterate through a specific column with sql commands i get errors stating a particular query can not be run. rather than going through all the sql commands within my excel file to figure out which does not work, how can i get my for loop to also give me the ones that do not work instead? because right now the for loop stops on the first error it gets.

class Analysis:

```
def read_sql(self):
    d1 = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
    d2 = pd.dataframe(columns=[['ID', 'written_query', 'short_desc']])
    d2['ID'] = d1['analysis_id']
    d2['written_query'] = d1['query_syntax']
    d2['description'] = d1['short_desc']
    d2 = d2.to_json()
    conn = pyodbc.connet("driver, server, database, trusted_connection")
    for query in d1['query_syntax']:
        df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
    return(df)
```

The error i receive is pandas.io.sqlDatabaseError

Example query error
select col2, col3, from t1

invalid column name 'col2'

i can easily go back and fix the column name i just have 100's of queries and i rather receive a list that tells me which ones i need to go back and fix rather than going through all of them one query error at a time.

Comment: this is actually not running the query's as it cycles through them it just returns a list of the ran querys as well as the failed ones how would i write the out put for the successful ones as well as the list of the failed ones. apologies for not being clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def read_sql(self):
    d1 = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
    d2 = pd.dataframe(columns=[['ID', 'written_query', 'short_desc']])
    d2['ID'] = d1['analysis_id']
    d2['written_query'] = d1['query_syntax']
    d2['description'] = d1['short_desc']
    d2 = d2.to_json()
    conn = pyodbc.connet("driver, server, database, trusted_connection")
    keep_fails = []
    for query in d1['query_syntax']:
        try:
            df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
        except:
            keep_fails.append(query)
    return(df, keep_fails)
```

Comment: worth noting: for each "query" you are overwriting "df". So ultimately what you will get returned is only the last successful query, and the list of failures.

Comment: As well as what @Aidan's mentioned above - you also really don't want a bare `except` here... catch the most specific error so something else doesn't get silently swallowed, so in this case, it'd be: `except pd.io.sql.DatabaseError`